# Ubuntu nautilus window control duplicate

Tags: unity, nautilus

I'm having problem with my nautilus on ubuntu. As you can see, the Close Button, Maximize Button, and Minimize button are duplicated. But whenever I launch nautilus as Root, it works fine. There are black corners too on file manager window. This only happens in Nautilus.

[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks like you're not using the default nautilus that comes with Ubuntu, maybe you installed (through a PPA?) a Gnome version. The Ubuntu version comes with some Unity patches to prevent what's happening to you. Can you check if you're nautilus version comes from a different source than the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: To investigate Felipe's suggestion, could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy nautilus`? Thanks.

Comment: I remembered installing different desktop environments in my machine. May that caused the issue.